# Why Encoding giving different results?

Tags: encoding, base64

This is my string

```
<Auth uid="" tid="" ver="" txn="" lk=""><Meta udc="" fdc="" idc="" pip="" lot="P" lov=""/><Skey ci="">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</Skey><Data type="">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</Data><Hmac>4c4a58555a484c6a4651486d344a6b586f586131536555573373594a30757768593046345435644c336677576a2b65682b686e416e6d52634878383751767632</Hmac></Auth>
```

And I am using This Code

```
    public String encode(String orig)
    {
    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(orig.getBytes());      



    System.out.println("Original String: " + orig );

    String s=new String(encoded);

    System.out.println("Base64 Encoded String : " + new String(encoded));
        return s;

   }
```

and output is

```
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
```

but when I use online BAse 64 encoder it gives output

```
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
```

Last digits are changed 
Why is that?

Comment: Thanks for editing !!!

Comment: You're welcome :-) @Mudit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you have extra `"\n"` at the end of second string. It can be seen easy if you run this command:

```
echo "your base 64 encoded string"|base64 -d|hexdump -C
```

in the linux shell

Comment: @Mudit What did you mean saying "right"? Both strings are right base64 encoded presentation for two different strings - first without `eol` at end and second with `eol` at end.

Comment: @Mudit, obviously, online encoder adds `\n` sequence to string before converting. So I think for your program first string is "right".